# Duplicate 'caption' on Facebook OpenGraph feed

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-opengraph, rest-client

The following 'error' started occurring within the past few month or so.  Up until then the following Ruby code (using the fantastic rest-client gem):

```
resp = RestClient.post("https://graph.facebook.com/#{userid}/feed",
                :access_token => fb_token,
                :picture      => picture,
                :message      => message,
                :caption      => caption)
```

has been working without issue.  Now, however, a call such as this is generating duplication caption text on a user's wall or news feed in PC browsers (oddly enough I have not seen it on mobile or tablet browsers).  For example, if the call:

```
resp = RestClient.post("https://graph.facebook.com/#{userid}/feed",
                :access_token => fb_token,
                :picture      => picture,
                :message      => "So-and-so just scored 1000 points!",
                :caption      => "Come join them!")
```

on the wall you would see the message, followed by a picture box, and

Come join them!Come join them!

displayed in the caption, where one would expect simply 'Come join them!' to be displayed as the caption.

Has anyone else had such an issue with Facebook's OpenGraph feed API?  I can include a link and name in the message and the duplicate caption goes away, but decided it appeared a bit too "spammy" on a user's wall.

Comment: According to docs, parameters `picture` and `caption` are only supposed to work if a `link` is supplied as well.

Comment: A URL to said documentation?  I have never seen that.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts